# Symfony2 AngularJS getting Symfony session variable in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, symfony, session

Is there any way of getting Symfony session variable in AngularJS. In Symfony I can get that variable like that: 
`$this->get('session')->get('_locale')`

Answer (score 0):

You must have a symfony action that give you the value, and call this action with an ajax call.
For exemple :

In a symfony controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/getLocale", name="getLocale")
 * @Template()
 */    
public function getLocaleAction(Request $request) {
    $data = ...;
    return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($data);
}
```

In an angular file :

```
$http.get('getLocale').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     alert(data);
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     ...  
});
```